# Word to combine two ends of a range that doesn't imply one end of the range is better than the other

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I'm attempting to describe a range without implying that one side of the range is better than the other.  I'm working on a presentation and attempting to keep it as succinct as possible. This isn't the only range so I'm hoping to find a word or phrase that fits.

The range is Creativity ---- Standardization.

*Creativity **vs** Standardization* -- this makes it into a boolean choice of one or the other instead of a range.

*Creativity **to** Standardization* -- feels directional, like one starts with Creativity and moves towards Standardization.

*Creativity **through** Standardization* -- feels like one uses Standardization to achieve Creativity.

*Creativity **through to** Standardization* -- feels awkward

Comment: It might help to write a full sentence as just how best to do this might depend on the overall context. Incidentally I think work in your title is probably meant to be word. You can edit it.

Comment: You might consider these examples: "Creativity and standardization represent a continuum of efficiency.   Where we should fall on the continuum depends on the situation. "  A second possibility: "In trying to maximize efficiency, creativity and standardization are in tension, and this graph represents a range of the positions where the contributions of these two opposites might be maximized, depending on the situation."  A third approach: "Creativity and standardization seem like polar opposites, but they really represent a range of possibilities where they both contribute something."

Comment: @Vegawatcher - Thank you for the examples. These got me working through the problem from a different angle.

Comment: @ColleenV - Thank you for the formatting. It does make it easier to distinguish the difference in my examples.

Comment: "Creativity through Standardization -- feels like one uses Standardization to achieve Creativity."  No, not to this English speaker.  For example, you can say "The colors range from red through green", and it doesn't mean that you use green to achieve red.  *through* can mean "by means of", but it's also a very natural word to use with ranges.

Comment: @ToddF My pleasure. Welcome to ELL! In general, comments that just say "thanks" are discouraged on Stack Exchange. It seems kind of unfriendly at first, but it does keep the space under questions and answers from getting cluttered. For more discussion about that policy, take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'and' between creativity and standardisation, which implies that we are always between the two extremes.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a presentation as your comment suggests then if I was putting it on a slide I would suggest

> Continuum Creativity Standardization

as a heading or bullet point. You could put continuum last as well.

Answer (score 0):

A range that doesn't extend from a starting point to an ending point isn't really a range, it's a set of things. If you are talking about a continuum where things gradually change their mix of "creative" and "standard", directionality is necessary. Arbitrarily choosing one point as a starting point doesn't necessarily make it "better".

For example, a rainbow is a range of colors. We choose to arrange it by wavelength. That doesn't mean that blue is a better color than red. I think you could use "continuum" as mdewey suggested in their answer to make it clear that it's not a boolean choice, and still use "to" without implying creativity is better:

> The Creativity to Standardization Continuum

It really is a personal bias to think of that range with "creativity" being the high point and it decaying toward standardization, or "standardization" being the desirable state that the range ascends to, or that the range is just a spectrum like a rainbow and there are lots of nice spots in the entire range. The way you discuss it in your presentation will provide your audience with the context to interpret the range correctly.

Comment: All good points. I agree that if I was discussing colors then there wouldn't be a misinterpretation of bias. Unfortunately, in this context I'm viewed as someone who leans to heavily on one end of this continuum (nice word :^D). That's why I'm being overly diligent to make sure the presentation, whether given by me or just forwarded, comes across as neutral and taken on its actual merits. People tend to stop listening or only listen for missteps once they feel like their is a counter-agenda to their point of view.
-